# Fresh install of 12.10 and many icons not showing on the Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

After a brand new install of 12.10 many of the icons are not showing on the Launcher on the left.  If you hover mouse over them the description is shown and clicking on them activates the application.

Terminal, home folder, system settings, Synaptic Package Manager and workspace switcher are all just blank.

From  dash if I search for any of the missing icons listed above the icon looks like a blank sheet of paper

All suggestions appreciated

Comment: @Harrison is right, it might just be the icons. Try installing a Numix icon theme, those ones have a crap-ton of icons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My icons are working fine, but I can get something like what you're describing by deleting stuff out of /usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps. I would try changing themes to see if that makes it work. Otherwise, look around /usr/share/icons to see if anything is missing.

For example, my Terminal icon is found in /usr/share//apps//utilities-terminal.svg.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I changed from Ambiance to Radiance and all icons reappeared.  Even if I go back to Ambiance the icons remain. Problem solved